# Title in Popup not changing dynamically

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to change the popup title based on the result of the function. If the data was found "name = StringProperty("") needs to change to string StringProperty("Data Exists Already"), if data not found StringProperty("Data Not Found"). The confirmationtext function seems to run fine but the variable " name " not getting new string? Or it does but I am not assigning correctly in the .kv file? Any suggestions.

class in .py

```
class ConfirmationPopUp(Popup):
name = StringProperty("")
def confirmationtext(self,fileName):
    print(fileName)
    data_exist = function.data_exist(fileName)
    print(data_exist)
    
    if data_exist == 1:
        #print("found 1")
        self.name = StringProperty("Data Exists Already") 
        Factory.ConfirmationPopUp().open() 
    else:
        self.name = StringProperty("Data Not Found") 
        Factory.ConfirmationPopUp().open() 
        #print("not found 1")
```

kv file

```
<ConfirmationPopUp@Popup>:
id: conf_popup
auto_dismiss: False
title: root.name
title_align:"center"
size_hint:(None,None)
size:(350,125)
AnchorLayout: 
    size_hint: 1,1
    anchor_y: "top"
    anchor_x: "center"
    spacing: dp(10)
    padding: [dp(8),dp(8),dp(8),dp(8)]
    AnchorLayout: 
        anchor_y: "center"
        anchor_x: "left"
        ButtDash:
            text: "Yes"
            size_hint: 0.49, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
            on_release: self.file_confirmation()
            on_press: root.dismiss()
    AnchorLayout: 
        anchor_y: "center"
        anchor_x: "right"
        ButtDash:
            text: "No"
            size_hint: 0.49, 0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "y":0.1}
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: change self.name = StringProperty("Data Exists Already")  to self.name = "Data Exists Already"  otherwise you are creating an entirely new object and assigning it to that variable instead of just updating the value inside the existing object

Comment: Thanks Mark, this worked. I think something is wrong with how I open the popup, is not getting a new value but the string from name = StringProperty(""). Any suggestions why when I open the popup is not getting new value from self.name?